# Purpose of key evolution?

Tags: diffie-hellman, keys, signal-protocol

When generating and exchanging keys, what is the purpose of performing key evolution after public key exchange + authenticated encryption?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the purpose of performing key evolution after the public key exchange and authenticated encryption is to provide forward secrecy. While generating and exchanging keys there are two security objectives. First, partial send deniability, which is provided by the public key exchange and authenticated encryption. Second, the forward and backward secrecy, provided by the key evolution.

Comment: Do you do key evolution for either secret keys or public keys or both?

Answer (score 1):

One of the main reasons for key evolution (aka 'key ratcheting') is so that you don't need to renegotiate key protocols for secure communication. Rather, you can update the previously used key, saving time and energy. It's important that old keys are deleted as when you update to the new key (no need to save them). On top of that, as was said above, key evolution also provides forward secrecy because you aren't long term storing and reusing old keys. So even if one private key is compromised, your whole exchange will not be compromised. Definitely read more about the Double Ratchet Algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Ratchet_Algorithm) if you have more questions about the importance of key evolution.